# Deserialization of an image from string with unknown encoding

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I have a set of serialized images which I want to deserialize. The data looks like the following:

```
GIF89ax\000\364\001\367\000\000\000\000\000\001\001\001\002\002\002\003\003\003\004\004\004\005\005\005\006\006\006\a\a\a\b\b\b\t\t\t\n\n\n\v\v\v\f\f\f\r\r\ ...
```

Due to data privacy I cann't post an full image. I have trouble to find out what kind of encoding this is. Now I'm struggeling to find a away to convert this to an `BufferedImage` in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the images were serialzed with Google-Protocoll Buffer `TextFormat`. So the code which converted the code correctly is

```
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;
import com.google.protobuf.TextFormat;

String imgStr = "GIF89ax\000\364\001\367\000\000\000\000\000\001\001\001\002\002\002\003\003\003\004\004\004\005\005\005\006\006\006\a\a\a\b\b\b\t\t\t\n\n\n\v\v\v\f\f\f\r\r\ ..."; // must an full image string
ByteString unescapeBytes = TextFormat.unescapeBytes(imgStr);
byte[] bytes = new byte[unescapeBytes.size()];
unescapeBytes.copyTo(bytes, 0);

final BufferedOutputStream bw = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("result.gif"));
bw.write(bytes);
bw.close();
```

Thats it.